# How to call a function after it is defined? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, function

How to call function B from inside A?

Function B has elements from A.

It gives me undefined function error.

```
    this.field = new Ext.form.TwinTriggerField( {
        width : this.width,
        selectOnFocus : undefined === this.selectOnFocus ? true
                : this.selectOnFocus,
        trigger1Class : 'x-form-clear-trigger',
        trigger2Class : this.minChars ? 'x-hidden'
                : 'x-form-search-trigger',
        onTrigger1Click : function() {
        this.setValue(''); 
        this.focus();

        this.Search(); // <----- error, this.Search is not defined

        },
        onTrigger2Click : this.onTriggerSearch.createDelegate(this),
        minLength : this.minLength
    });

    function Search() {
       var length = this.field.getValue().toString().length;

       if (0 === length || this.minChars <= length) {
            caller = this;          
            this.triggerCount++;
            this.grid.store.proxy.getConnection().abort(); 
            setTimeout("caller.onTriggerSearch()",this.triggerDelay);   
       }
    }
```

it says that `this` is not defined

Comment: can you show us a minimalistic code?

Comment: I could ask the magic ball, but it's probably more accurate you post your code.

Comment: Elements?  Method parameters?  Variables (from a closure)? DOM elements? this is the DOMWindow.

Comment: It is huge! Very very huge. See Ext Js.

Comment: `setTimeout("caller.onTriggerSearch()",this.triggerDelay);`  Should be `setTimeout(caller.onTriggerSearch,this.triggerDelay);`.  Passing strings to `setTimeout` `eval`s them in the global scope, so it doesn't know what `caller` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function a(){
    var el1=document.body;
    var el2=document.body.innerHTML;
    b(el1,el2);
}

function b(num1, num2){
   alert(num1.length);
   alert(num2.length);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What is 'this' in your current context? Search is probably not defined in that context. You should just use `Search()`. However, you need to pass the object into your search function.

**Edit:**
Also you do not pass anything into your Search function so 'this' doesnt exist.